# How to check all invalid synonyms in Oracle

Tags: oracle, synonym

I have the table user_synonyms in which I can see the name, table and table owner. Is there a way to see if this synonym is still valid i,e. if the referencing table still exists without trying it manually?

Answer (score 5):

You can check whether the table exists by joining on ALL_TABLES (a synonym might not be on a table in the same schema).

```
select *
  from all_synonyms s
  left outer join all_tables t
    on s.table_owner = t.owner
   and s.table_name = t.table_name
 where s.owner = user
```

Add the condition `and t.table_name is null` if you want those synonyms where the table does not exist.

If you want to check whether the synonym is VALID query [ALL_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1155.htm#REFRN20146).

```
select *
  from all_synonyms s
  join all_objects o
    on s.owner = o.owner
   and s.synonym_name = o.object_name
 where o.object_type = 'SYNONYM'
   and s.owner = user
   and o.status <> 'VALID'
```

---

As a_horse_with_no_name points out in the comments there is no requirement for a synonym to be on a table, views, sequences even packages are all valid.

So, you might want to change the first query to look for these as well:

```
select *
  from all_synonyms s
  join all_objects o
    on s.table_owner = o.owner
   and s.table_name = o.object_name
 where s.owner = user
```

Comment: To complete the picture: a synonym is not necessarily for a table. So the first query might produce false negatives if the synonym points e.g. to a view or a procedure.

Comment: True @a_horse_with_no_name, concentrated too much on the question. I've updated my answer; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct os.*
from   all_objects os
      ,all_synonyms s
where 1 = 1
and   os.object_type = 'SYNONYM'
and   os.STATUS      = 'INVALID'
and   os.object_name = s.synonym_name
and   not exists     ( select unique(1)
                       from   all_objects o1
                       where  o1.object_name = s.TABLE_NAME
                       and    o1.owner       = s.TABLE_OWNER)
order by 2;
```

Comment: You should give some discription

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
select s.table_owner, s.table_name 
from all_synonyms  s, all_tables t  
where s.table_owner = t.owner(+)
and s.table_name = t.table_name(+)
and t.owner is null
--s.owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
;
```

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name said in the other answer, _a synonym is not necessarily for a table. So the first query might produce false negatives if the synonym points e.g. to a view or a procedure._